# Planetlab and scapy: MAC address to reach destination not found

Tags: python, ip, fedora, mac-address

Using the minimal **Fedora 14** distribution provided in **PlanetLab**, I'm forging packets through `Scapy` and sending them with `tcpreplay`.

I thought I had installed all the necessary **packages** to run `scapy` and `tcpreplay`, but for some reason `scapy` can't access the mac address of the machine.

For instance, if I send a packet through `Scapy`, I always get:

```
"WARNING: Mac address to reach destination not found. Using broadcast."
```

Also, if I add an **Ethernet** layer to an existing IP packet, the resulting **destination** is always `ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured out what was happening:

- On **PlanetLab** you can't make any **ARP** requests, even if you are root. You can only read the **ARP table** that is provided to you
- When **Scapy** builds an **Ethernet layer** with no input destination address, it makes an **ARP request** to fill out that field of the Ethernet header.

**=> Solution**: I had to lookup the ARP table myself and specify the gateway's MAC address in each packet.